# Segmentation fault,C++,g++,

Tags: c++

I have this simple program, when I run this program, I get segmentation fault, I can not 
recognize where is my mistake. any help welcomed.(segmentation fault for Di>=27). The point
is that when I remove function immediately segmentation fault disappears. Or when I transform the function to a void function. I know there is a leak memory because not uses delete operator,
it causes leak memory,but easily is not responsible for segmentation fault(This leak memory is very far to produce segmentation fault).for simplicity I didn't use delete operator.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include<complex>
    using namespace std;
    const int Di=27;
    typedef struct {
         complex<double> Matrix[Di][Di][Di][Di];

        } O;

    O initializing(int );

    int main()
    {
    O * Operator=new O[1];
    int p;
    int n;
    Operator[0]=initializing(n);
    cout<<"hi";
    return 0;

    }



O initializing(int  point)
{
int i,j,m,n;
O *Operator=new O[1];
for(i=0;i<Di-1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<Di-1;j++)
        for(n=0;n<Di-1;n++)
            for(m=0;m<Di-1;m++)
            Operator[0].Matrix[i][j][m][n]=2;

            cout<<Operator[0].Matrix[Di-1][Di-1][Di-1][Di-1];
return Operator[0];


}
```

Comment: A strange thing in your method initializing() is that you are consistently using the condition "... < Di-1". This leaves the outer element of each dimension un-initialized or default-initialized, if applicable.
Your output at the end references an un-initialized element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a struct with a large array by value, and it does not fit on the stack. Return the struct by pointer, and dereference that pointer in the caller. It would help you avoid a memory leak, too.

```
O* initializing(int );

int main()
{
    O * Operator=new O[1];
    int p;
    int n;
    O *tmp = initializing(n);
    Operator[0] = *tmp;
    delete[] tmp;
    cout<<"hi";
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You are absolutely sure that temporary object created on the stack?or you're guessing ?

Comment: @reza The standard does not require it to be the case, but that is a typical way the compilers do it. From the description of your error it appears that your particular compiler does it like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your respond was very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that, when returning the object by value, a temporary object might be created on the stack. With `Di=27`, each object is a few megabytes in size, which is likely to overflow the stack.

You're also allocating (and leaking) at least twice as much memory as you need, by initialising a new object to copy over the existing object.

Better options might be to pass the object to initialise to the function by reference:

```
void initialise(O & o, int point) {
    for (/*blah blah*/)
        o.Matrix[i][j][m][n]=2;
}
```

or to give the structure a constructor:

```
struct O {
    explicit O(int point) {
        for (/*blah blah*/)
            Matrix[i][j][m][n]=2;
    }

    complex<double> Matrix[Di][Di][Di][Di];
};
```

In any case, do remember to delete anything you allocate with `new`; or, even better, use a smart pointer to do that for you.

Comment: You are absolutely sure that temporary object created on the stack?or you're guessing ?

Comment: It is implementation defined. On one compiler it may produce code that puts the result on the stack, on another it may do it on the heap, on yet another it may put the data on the laser beam bouncing off the moon. Don't depend on anything particular happening, or not happening. Big objects must live on the heap, that's the only portable way.

Comment: @reza: I'm guessing, but that's the only problem I can see (apart from the memory leaks). If a temporary is created, then it will almost certainly be on the stack. The compiler might elide the temporary if optimisations are enabled, but it's not safe to assume that.